# Proceed with redirect after dialog confirm item clicked

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using the jQuery Dialog box to confirm a link click, but somehow the dialog does not wait for the correct confirmation before proceeding with the default event handler. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#dialog-submit-vp-confirm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit to VP": function() {
                // Proceed with click here
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    $("#submit_to_vp").click(function(e) {
        $( "#dialog-submit-vp-confirm" ).dialog("open");
    });
});
```

And **HTML**:

```
<div id="dialog-submit-vp-confirm" title="Submit to your VP">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Your plan will now be submitted to your VP. Are you sure you want to proceed?</p>
</div>
<a href="' . JURI::root() . 'api/submit_plan.php?plan_id=' . $plan_id . '" class="btn button" style="float: right;" id="submit_to_vp">Submit to VP</a>
```

Please ignore any PHP/Joomla in the HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
 $("#submit_to_vp").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $( "#dialog-submit-vp-confirm" ).dialog("open");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort of got my answer here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-make-the-dialog-widget-modal-confirmation-redirect-to-another-site-when-i-click-one-of-the-options

Thanks for the answers.

I changed my code to this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var href = "";

    $( "#dialog-submit-vp-confirm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit to VP": function() {
                // Proceed with click here
                location = href;
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

    $("#submit_to_vp").click(function(e) {
        href=this.href;
        $("#dialog-submit-vp-confirm").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```